# Syntax for creating temp table with their unique name by select query in stored procedure using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create temp table with their unique name by a select query in a stored procedure in SQL Server.

For example: whenever I run the select query at that time different temp table name want to create.

Let be more clear, at the first time when I will run the select query at that time temptable name is `temptable1`, while at the second time the table name will be `temptable2` and so on.

I want to know the syntax for executing the select query and creating the temptable with their unique name in a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: Why you need to do this?

Comment: Bcos I want to generate same temptable for different user

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the SQL Server Stored Procedure, the engine is handling itself the names of the temporary tables.

There is no need to worry if many users are executing the same stored procedure in same time - the temporary objects cannot be shared across them and no conflicts are going to happen.

Also, naming a temporary table in stored procedure with different name can be done using a dynamic T-SQL statement. You can for example, use a sequence to get such number and concatenate it to the table name. But, if you do so, you need to use `sp_executesql` to create your table and do things with it. In such way, no other stored procedure would be able to read/modify the table you have created in the current stored procedure. In other words, the temporary table cannot be shared over the routines if created using dynamic T-SQL statement. So, there is absolutely no point of doing such thing.